# Get tab id of tab where script is executing in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Within a chrome extension, is there a way to get the tab where a piece of javascript s executing.

The usual way to do this is:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){});
```

But there is a problem here, that when this code executes, the tab which initiated this script might not be in focus, and you will get the current active tab.

Imagine the following extension page and script:

URL: chrome-extension//my-extension-id/index.html

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='index.js'></script>
```

URL: chrome-extension//my-extension-id/index.js

```
setTimeout(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        console.log(tabs[0]);
    });
},5000);
```

If you open the url with the html file, and switch tabs in less than 5 seconds, you will get the new tab in the console log. Is there a way to get the original tab?

An obvious solution is first to get the active tab, and then schedule the timeout, but still there are cases where you might open the tab without making it active, for example with right click + open in new tab.

So is there a way to get the id of the tab that initiated the script?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.getCurrent

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, that is it. I saw it in other answers, but somehow confused it with getSelected, which the docs say it is deprecated.